# Using pointers to write to a std container

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, iterator

I'd like to be able to create a fixed-length container (`vector`? `deque`?) to act a buffer, and then give another vector of objects a pointer to the location of the buffer where they are allowed to write in.

Example (not compileable code)

```
class Item {
  *p //pointer to a place in the vector
  vector<int> values
}

vector<Item> items;

for(auto item : items) {
  for(auto value : values) {
    buffer[p] = item->value
    ++(item->p);
  }
}
```

However, I'm not sure how to make the relationship where it's clear to each `Item` where they should start writing in the buffer.

I should note that for each iteration over `items`, the final buffer has a known fixed size -- but between function calls, the number of `Items` could change.

thanks,

Comment: You mean like std::array?

Comment: I don't think that `std::array` would work, because for every iteration over my items, the final buffer size is known, but between functions calls the size of `items` could change.  I'm also not sure how to give each `Item` a pointer to where it should start writing.

Comment: `then use pointers to have items write to certain parts of the vector to create a buffer`  If that vector gets resized, those pointers you set up could eventually point to trash since a vector's iterators can become invalidated.

Comment: I'm still lost in parsing the *question*. "...use pointers to have items write to certain parts of the vector to create a buffer" - writing to a vector doesn't "create" *anything*. Is there any chance you could put up an actual example. I.e. "Suppose my vector looked like... I want to be able to do....".

Comment: Pointers to values contained in `std::vector<>` aren't stable. That's not a good idea! Consider using indices, or even [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory), if you really need this.

Comment: I can't help but agree with @πάνταῥεῖ. Regardless of what you are actually trying to do (still unclear on that), either direct data pointers or live iterators to a dynamic vector is generally a bad idea unless you've synthetically capped it with a `.reserve()` and never exceed that capacity. (and even then, I wouldn't advise it, as it makes for what are eventually time-bomb-defects).

Comment: /agree with all of the above, it's a bad, bad, idea.

Comment: Well, I did say that I didn't know what container to use.  I want to create a buffer (can be a `vector`, c-style array, or `std::array`), and then have each `Item` have a clear pointer / index / something to tell it where it allowed to write in the buffer.

Comment: @nathanlachenmyer Are you looking for something like a [_ring / circular buffer_ solution](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/38815/one-reader-one-writer-no-memory-allocation-lock-free-ring-buffer)?

Answer (score 4):

If I've understood the question correctly (which I'm not sure about), you should use an index, not a pointer or an iterator, because it is a relative offset to the start of the buffer, not an absolute address that would be invalidated by changes to the buffer.

```
class Item
{
  size_t pos;  // index into the buffer
  vector<int> values;
};

vector<Item> items;
// ...
std::vector<int> buffer;
buffer.resize(N);
for (auto& item : items)
{
  assert(buffer.size() >= (item.pos + item.values.size()));
  std::copy(std::begin(item.values), std::end(item.values),
            std::begin(buffer)+item.pos);
}
```

This will work with either a `vector` or `deque` as the buffer (or anything else with RandomAccessIterators), but as you don't appear to need to add/remove elements at the start of the buffer (only resize it once and assign to existing elements) then there is no reason to use `deque. Therefore you should prefer`vector`, which should generally be your default choice of container unless you need the particular characteristics of one of the other containers.

I don't know how you plan to set the `Item::pos` values, maybe this would make sense:

```
size_t pos = 0;
for (auto& item : items)
{
  item.pos = pos;
  pos += item.values.size();
  assert(buffer.size() >= pos);
  std::copy(std::begin(item.values), std::end(item.values),
            std::begin(buffer)+item.pos);
}
```

This would put each item in turn into the buffer, and record the position on the fly.

This could even be made to work without knowing the total buffer size in advance, resizing the buffer as needed:

```
size_t pos = 0;
for (auto& item : items)
{
  item.pos = pos;
  pos += item.values.size();
  if (buffer.size() < pos)
    buf.resize(pos);
  std::copy(std::begin(item.values), std::end(item.values),
            std::begin(buffer)+item.pos);
}
```

Because you're storing an index, not an absolute address, it continues to work even after the buffer is resized and its contents relocated to a different block of memory.

Answer (score 2):

> I should note that for each iteration over `items`, the final buffer has a known fixed size -- but between function calls, the number of `Items` could change.

As stated in my comment, pointers and references you'll take and track for a value contained in a `std::vector<whatever>` aren't stable, as long the vector is a allowed to be changed by `push_back()`, `erase()` or any other operations of this kind.

---

Though, you have the options to

- Refer to indices of the vector. These ***will be stable***, even if the `std::vector<>` needs to reallocate and copy.
- Use [***smart pointers***](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) like
  `std::unique_ptr<>` or `std::shared_ptr<>` to be stored in the `std::vector<>` instead of the instance copies.

It totally depends on your actual use case, which would be the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already commented, I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve but your original code is not that far away from something that can be compiled and has well-defined (though rather useless) behavior.

I think you might have intended to write the following:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Item
{
  std::vector<int>::iterator p;
  std::vector<int> values;

  Item() : values {'H', 'A', 'P', 'P', 'Y'}
  {
    this->p = values.begin();
  }
};

std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Item& item)
{
  os << "[";
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < item.values.size(); ++i)
    os << (i ? ", " : "") << item.values.at(i);
  os << "]";
  return os;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<Item> items {4};
  for (auto& item : items)
    {
      for (auto value : item.values)
        {
          *(item.p) = value;  // Note: self-assignment with no effect
          ++(item.p);
        }
    }
  for (auto& item : items)
    std::cout << item << std::endl;
}
```

This particular program is well-behaved but using this data structure, you will most likely shoot yourself in the foot sooner or later.  There probably is a better solution.