# access contents of another form of array in C++

Tags: c++, vector, 2d

How can I access a particular position in a 2d vector, say
vector < vector < int >* >

```
     vector<int> m1{4,7,9,0}; 
     //similarly assigned values to m2, m3, m4, m5;
     vector<vector<int>* > matrix{&m1,&m2,&m3,&m4,&m5};
```

now how can I access an element from the vector matrix that is coming from say matrix[3][1] and assign a value explicitly.

Thank you

Comment: Use `vector<vector<int> >`

Comment: actually I want to access for a vector<vector<int>* > in specific

Comment: Then it's `(*matrix[3])[1]` but you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: +1 for *but you are probably doing something wrong.*

Comment: This is also relevant for you to know: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26287637/using-pointers-to-write-to-a-std-container/26287913#26287913

Comment: You should probably create a wrapper class (called `vectorptr` or something similar) that overloads `operator[] ()`. Then you can have `vector<vectorptr<int>>` and you should be able to call `matrix[3][1]` as you expect.

Comment: Thanks to all, your comments helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

You could also do

```
matrix[3]->at(1);
```